# When should I use useMemo? What is an "expensive component"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

I am a bit confused about what's the proper way to use useMemo. Reading here ([Should I wrap every prop with useCallback or useMemo, when to use this hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310682/should-i-wrap-every-prop-with-usecallback-or-usememo-when-to-use-this-hooks)) it says that I have to use it for *expensive children*, so what does that mean exactly? Can someone provide a real life example?

I created a new React project playing around with 2 different approaches.

You can check the full code here (in the same page you can switch from one method to the other):

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-rgb-fz60n

In this first example I pass to `AppContext` an object containing `userState` and `setUserState` (logged or not).

```
  const [userState, setUserState] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialUserState);

  const appState = {
    userState,
    setUserState
  }

  <AppContext.Provider value={appState}>
```

Would this approach be acceptable?

In the second example, I use useMemo:

```
const [userState, setUserState] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialUserState);

  const value = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      userState,
      setUserState
    };
  }, [userState]);

<AppContext.Provider value={value}>
```

So I suppose that useMemo in this second case it's not a good choice since the children is not *expensive*. Is this correct?

Comment: You also need to consider that, if `userState` is unchanged, everything that consumes `AppContext` will re-render unnecessarily because `appState` is a different reference on every render. So `useMemo()` will prevent that.

Comment: What does exactly mean "everything that consumes AppContext"?

Comment: As in every occurence of [`<AppContext.Consumer>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) in the component hierarchy...

Comment: In my code I'm not using `<AppContext.Consumer>`. In the child component I have `const value = React.useContext(AppContext);` and `const value = React.useContext(AppContext);` is it the same?

Comment: Yes `useContext()` accomplishes the same.