# What is the best case for defining function without any dependencies in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm always confused when define function in React functional component without any dependencies.

For example,

```
const HelloWorld = () => {
  const getHelloWorldText = useCallback(() => {
    return "HelloWorld"
  }, [])

  return <>{getHelloWorldText()}</>
}
```

It's a simplified component, just imagine `HelloWorld` is updated every 5 seconds. `useCallback` is needed for optimization preventing redefine.

However, it's possible like below.

```
const getHelloWorldText = () => {
  return "HelloWorld"
}

const HelloWorld = () => {
  return <>{getHelloWorldText()}</>
}
```

If there's no dependency, above example is more costless than `useCallback` example, but it's not a pure function.

Which do you prefer? And why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310682/should-i-wrap-every-prop-with-usecallback-or-usememo-when-to-use-this-hooks

Answer (score 1):

Prematurely using `useCallback` to optimise can often lead to worse performance.
It is recommended to only start using it when you have a measurable performance issue, so you can test whether the overhead of `useCallback` is worth the memoization it brings.

Also, in your example code, because the dependency array at the end is empty, it will always return the same value, as `useCallback` works by only re-running the given function  when a variable in that array has changed.

---

This is what I would do:

```
const HelloWorld = () => {
  const getHelloWorldText = () => {
    return "HelloWorld"
  }

  return <>{getHelloWorldText()}</>
}
```